# Check for custom field value in different post type than current one and do something

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query, post-meta, meta-value

I have 2 post types, one is for my posts and the other one is used as a submission form.

When a user is on a single post page for post type A, I am trying to do several checks to then display content -

1) I'm checking if the user is logged in

2) if he has published any posts (submitted forms) in post type B

3) If so is custom field (1) in authors published posts in post type B empty or not

4) If its not empty, does the value match the value of custom field (2) of any posts in post type A that is currently being viewed

This is what I have so far ---

```
<?php 
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$balance = mycred_get_users_balance( $user_id, 'piq_credits' );
if( (is_user_logged_in()) && (piq_user_has_posts($user->ID)) && ($balance != '0') ) { ?>
```

The piq_user_has_posts function is --

```
function piq_user_has_posts($user_id) {
  $result = new WP_Query(array(
    'author'=>$user_id,
    'post_type'=>'post_type_b',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>1,
  ));
  return (count($result->posts)!=0);
}
```

What I need now is to be able to check - **if $customfield1 = $customfield2 then do something**

Again, each custom field is from a different post type and Im doing this on a single post page for one of those post types.

So far I tried the following --

```
$users_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'piq_request',
    'meta_key' => 'piq_link',
    'meta_value' => $piq_link,
) );

//echo $piq_link;
echo $this_property_id;

if($piq_link == $this_property_id) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it almost working perfect. but I need to test my else statement(s) further.

I have this in my functions.php --

```
function piq_user_has_posts($user_id) {
  $result = new WP_Query(array(
    'author'=>$user_id,
    'post_type'=>'post_type_b',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>1,
  ));
  return (count($result->posts)!=0);
}
```

This on my single post page for post type a --

```
<?php

// GET USER INFO - SOME FIELDS ARE PROBABLY NOT NEEDED 
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

//$balance = mycred_get_users_balance( $user_id, 'piq_credits' );

// IN FUNCTIONS FILE HAS CODE FOR PIQ_USER_HAS_POSTS TO SEE IF THE USER HAS POSTS IN SPECIFIC CUSTOM POST TYPE. THEN I CHECK IF LOGGED IN
if( (piq_user_has_posts($user->ID)) && (is_user_logged_in()) ) { 

// ONCE THAT CHECKS OUT I RUN A QUERY FOR ALL THE POSTS IN POST TYPE B
$args = array(
  'numberposts'=> -1,           
  'post_type'=> 'post_type_b',
  'meta_key' => 'piq_link',
  'meta_value' => $this_property_id, // THE POST ID FOR THE POST WE ARE CURRENTLY ON IN POST TYPE A
  'author' => $user_id,
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

// IF USER POSTS MATCH THEN I GET THE VALUES NEEDED TO RUN MY OTHER CHECKS
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$piq_author = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$piq_link = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'piq_link',true);

// I CHECK IF ALL THE VALUES MATCH UP
if (($this_property_id == $piq_link) && ($user_id == $piq_author)) { ?>

<!-- STUFF I WANT TO SHOW IF EVERYTHING CHECKS OUT OK -->


<?php } // CLOSE IT OUT
endwhile;
endif; wp_reset_query(); // END THE LOOP ?>

<!-- IF USER HAS NO POSTS AND IS NOT LOGGED IN -->

<?php } else { ?>
NOPE
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I believe this will help you to get what you're after. I can't verify it works, but reading it should give some guidance:

```
function my_plugin_verify() {

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 1) I'm checking if the user is logged in
    if (!is_user_logged_in())
        return false; // NOT VERIFIED

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) if he has published any posts (submitted forms) in post_typeB
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // get all posts_typeB by $user_id
    $users_posts_typeB = get_posts(array(
                    'author' => $user_id,
                    'post_type' => 'post_typeB',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                ));

    // if no posts, NOT VERIFIED
    if (count($users_posts) < 1)
        return false; 

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 3) is custom_field_1 in $users_posts_typeB in post type B empty or not
    $custom_field_1_values = array();

    // cycle through post_typeB posts by $user_id
    foreach ($users_posts_typeB as $apost) {

        // see if custom_field_1 is not empty in all them
        $custom_field_1 = get_post_meta($apost->ID,'custom_field_1',true);

        // if custom_field_1 empty, user is NOT VERIFIED
        if (empty($custom_field_1) || empty($custom_field_1))
            return false; 

        // if custom_field_1 has value, record it for comparison next
        else
            $custom_field_1_values[]  = $custom_field_1;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 4) does the value match the value of custom field (2) of any posts in post type A that is currently being viewed

    // we'll presume no matches
    $matchFound = false;

    // we'll query all post_typeA, looking for a custom_field_2 with the value of all above custom_field_1 value's
    foreach ($custom_field_1_values as $custom_field_1_value) {
        $matchingCustomValue = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'post_typeA',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key' => 'custom_field_2',
            'meta_value' => $custom_field_1_value,
        ));

        // if there's a match, we'll note it
        if (count($matchingCustomValue) > 0)
            $matchFound = true;
    }

    // if there's no match, user is NOT VERIFIED
    if (!$matchFound)
        return false;

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 5) Is the mycred (plugin) balance is empty or not
    $balance = mycred_get_users_balance( $user_id, 'piq_credits' );
    if ($balance == '0')
        return false

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // they got this far, they're verified
    return true;
}
```

And you'd just argue the function

```
if ( my_plugin_verify() )
    // user meets criteria
    // display content
)
```

I'm wasn't sure what "is currently being viewed" meant in (4) and how you'd monitor that.

I wasn't sure if post_typeB would return more than one post, or if custom_field_1 could exists for a user more than one. I wrote it for multiples.

If your queries don't have to happen real-time and aren't constantly updating, you'll want to look into [transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to save the verification state instead of querying each time.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! What I meant in number 4 is that the user would be on a single post page when these checks are done. There isnt a need to search through all posts for the second custom field since it is a single post view, I only need to compare the value of the field for the post being viewed.